# Changing Adapter NetConnectionID using IWBemServices in Visual-C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wmi, adapter

I am trying to change the NetConnectionID value of a network adapter by creating an instance of the Win32_NetworkAdapter class using IWBemServices. I am locating the adapter by its DeviceId and then trying to put the new NetConnectionID into the instance.

I am not getting any errors, but the NetConnectionID remains unchanged.

This is what my function currently looks like:

```
int CIPConfigModule::setAdapterName(CString CAdapterName, unsigned int idAdapter)
{

    int bNoErrors = NO_ERROR;
    IWbemClassObject *pNewInstance = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject *pObjectClass = NULL;
    IWbemContext *pCtx = NULL;
    IWbemCallResult *pResult = NULL;

    // Get the class definition.
    string strIndex = std::to_string((long double)idAdapter);
    string strIndexCommand = "Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID=\"";
    strIndexCommand.append(strIndex).append("\"");
    CString CSIndexCommand = strIndexCommand.c_str();
    // BSTR PathToClass = SysAllocString(L"Example");

    HRESULT hRes = m_pSvc->GetObject((bstr_t)CSIndexCommand, 0, pCtx, 
                 &pObjectClass, &pResult);

    if (hRes != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR){
        bNoErrors=ERROR_ATTEMPTING_TO_CHANGE_NAME;
        return bNoErrors;
    }

    // Create a new instance.
    pObjectClass->SpawnInstance(0, &pNewInstance);
    pObjectClass->Release();  // Don't need the class any more

    VARIANT v;
    VariantInit(&v);

    // Set the NetConnectioID property.
    V_VT(&v) = VT_BSTR;
    V_BSTR(&v) = CAdapterName.AllocSysString();
    //V_BSTR(&v) = SysAllocString(L"Testing");
    BSTR KeyProp = SysAllocString(L"NetConnectionID");
    pNewInstance->Put(KeyProp, 0, &v, 0);
    SysFreeString(KeyProp);
    VariantClear(&v);

    // Other properties acquire the 'default' value specified
    // in the class definition unless otherwise modified here.

    // Write the instance to WMI. 
    hRes = m_pSvc->PutInstance(pNewInstance, 0, pCtx, &pResult);
    pNewInstance->Release();

    if (hRes != WBEM_S_NO_ERROR){
        bNoErrors=ERROR_ATTEMPTING_TO_CHANGE_NAME;
        return bNoErrors;
    }

    return bNoErrors;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I could be missing?

Comment: Try passing the `WBEM_FLAG_UPDATE_ONLY` value in the `PutInstance` method and `NULL` on the last parameters like so `hRes = m_pSvc->PutInstance(pNewInstance, WBEM_FLAG_UPDATE_ONLY, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Thanks, but after trying that, I am getting an HRESULT error 0x80041008 (WBEM_E_INVALID_PARAMETER). That error goes away when the &pResult is included instead of NULL, but there is still no changes to the adapter names... No error comes up, but nothing is change. Any other idea what could be wrong??